# Calculate value of $\theta$

Tags: trigonometry

Calculate the value of $\theta$ where;

$$\frac{\pi}{10} = \theta - \sin\theta,$$

I would really appreciate it, I have a feeling its grapheable.

Comment: [See this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transcendental_equation).

Answer (score 1):

question like this can be best handled by Wolfram Alpha. It finds the intersection of $y = x - \sin x$ and $y = \pi/10$ when both functions are graphed. The answer it displays is about 1.26895 (radian).

Comment: Please, use late markdown when possible.

Comment: @Matik Ken. Wolfram Alpha is great but I am not totally sure that it teaches anything to anyone. For this kind of problems, I prefer to have a plotter (say Excel) and to know some numerical recipes. I should appreciate your opinion on my statement. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Your equation cannot be solved analytically and needs to be solved numerically. If you plot the function f(x) = x - Sin(x) - Pi / 10, you can notice that there is a root close to x = 1.3. If you want to solve accurately, the best is using Newton method starting at say x_old=1.3.
The Newton iterates write
x_new = x_old - f(x_old) / f'(x_old)
Then, in your case, the successive iterates will be 1.26958, 1.26895 which is the solution given by Matik Ken.